# angular : delete some properties in obj with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

**here is my data :**

```
$scope.datas = {
      "name": "000",
      "id" : 1,
      "type" : "record"
      "children": [
        {name:111,id:2,children:[
          {name:444,id:5,children:[]}
        ]}
        {name:222,id:3,children:[]}
        {name:333,id:4,children:[]}
      ]
    }
```

**and this is my delete function :**

```
deleteNode = (node,id) ->
    if node.id == id
      $timeout ->
        console.log 'findNode',node
        node = null
        return
    if node.children
      for rows,i in node.children
        if rows.id == id
          $timeout ->
            console.log 'findNode',rows
            rows = null
        else
          deleteNode(rows,id)
```

I need to find the specified id in my `$scope.datas`

after I execute this function `deleteNode($scope.datas,5)`

it find the correct obj indeed,but the `$scope.datas` doesn't change,why?

> Found the answer,I change `deleteNode` function to blew

```
deleteNode = (node,id) ->
    if node.id == id
      $timeout ->
        node = {}
        return
    if node.children
      for rows,i in node.children
        if rows.id == id
          node.children.splice(i,1)
          return
        else
          deleteNode(rows,id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the object after you make the changes to it i.e.

```
deleteNode = (node,id) ->
    if node.id == id
      $timeout ->
        console.log 'findNode',node
        node = null
         // return the node 
        return node;
    if node.children
      for rows,i in node.children
        if rows.id == id
          $timeout ->
            console.log 'findNode',rows
            rows = null
            // return the node 
            return node;
        else
          deleteNode(rows,id)
```

Comment: github copilot suggested me a link to this answer to something not related at all LOL

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
deleteNode = (node,id) ->
 if node.id == id
   $timeout ->
     console.log 'findNode',node
     node = null
     $timeout(angular.noop)
    return
if node.children
  for rows,i in node.children
    if rows.id == id
      $timeout ->
        console.log 'findNode',rows
        rows = null
        $timeout(angular.noop)
    else
      deleteNode(rows,id)
```